# MappingException (Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

"Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister "

I am not using any maven or such tools and manually add and reference libraries.
I have gone through all the similar questions posted earlier and included all the relevant libs that might need to be included.
I am using Java 1.8,Hibernate 5 with the same compliance level.
All getters and setters also present and verified.
Unable to determine what's causing this.[PLEASE DON'T MARK THIS DUPLICATE AND LET ME KNOW IN COMMENTS IF YOU THINK I MISSED ANY POSSIBLE SOLUTION]

Student.java

```
package com.vv.hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
    public Student() {
    }
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
        
}
```

CreateStudentDemo.java( the main file)

```
package com.vv.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import com.vv.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws org.hibernate.MappingException {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        try {
            StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata metaData = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
//          .addAnnotatedClassName( "com.vv.hibernate.demo.entity" )
                    .getMetadataBuilder().build();
            sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder()
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try(Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            Student student = new Student("a", "b", "a@b.com");
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(student);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Transaction completed");
            session.close();
        } 
        catch (MappingException exception) {
            System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Console Errors:

```
    Feb 25, 2021 7:57:30 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:30 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1 (file:/C:/eclipseWKSP/hibernate-tutorial/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:31 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=hbstudent}
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:31 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Feb 25, 2021 7:57:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
Initial SessionFactory creation failed
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at com.vv.hibernate.demo.CreateStudentDemo.main(CreateStudentDemo.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(boolean)" because "ao" is null
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58)
    ... 21 more
```

[image]

Java Build Path config also attached:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also learn this online tutorial and meet the same problem. After trying various solutions, I find there are some clues:

1. **check all jars**

[lib folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01CFF.png)

2. **delete the module-info.java file**

Not sure about the reason but the second solution works well on both JavaSE-11 and JavaSE-17.

Answer (score 0):

1. First reason - some jars missing.
2. Second reason - put the same version for hibernate in all dependencies jars

Comment: Which version would you suggest for the hibernate jars. And which jars are missing ? My hibernate-jpa is compatible with hibernate ORM 5.2

Comment: Javassist  Two jars in the lib folder

Comment: The new answer is working just fine with two jars

Answer (score 0):

I still couldn't find the exact answer to above code but after retracing the tutorial i am following and by luck , the errors are gone . Will reshare the exact things that worked.
Also I was following udemy chad's tutorial so anyone who faces the same can reference this. Be very exact with jars versions (chad didn't include many in his).

Student.java was same as question

CreateStudentDemo.java ( I had to use old ORM code to get this to work)

```
package com.vv.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.vv.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            // create a student object
            System.out.println("Creating new student object...");
            Student tempStudent = new Student("Paul", "Doe", "paul@luv2code.com");

            // start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            // save the student object
            System.out.println("Saving the student...");
            session.save(tempStudent);

            // commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Done!");
        } finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

hibernate.cf.xml was also same as question

Console log

```
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.0.Final}
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1 (file:/C:/eclipseWKSP/hibernate-tut/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:07 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=hbstudent}
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:07 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Creating new student object...
Saving the student...
Hibernate: insert into student (email, first_name, last_name) values (?, ?, ?)
Done!
Feb 26, 2021 12:52:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
```

referenced libraries:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem, also following the same course by Chad on Udemy.
Removing javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar and adding the jar from [here](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases/download/rel_3_19_0_ga/javassist.jar) (version 3.19.0-GA ) fixed it for me.